# How can I ensure my data is properly loaded before rendering?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, react-hooks

I have a react app linked to my Firestore database and with firebase authentication integration. The problem is as such: upon first render, the loading screen works as intended. The console logs that it has loaded the data, however all data is empty. On the second render, most of the data except rfi.tender is loaded, and on the third the rfi.tender data loads. I am having to re render by adding whitespace to the file.

```
function HomePage() {
    const [allTenders, setAllTenders] = useState([]);
    const [userActiveTenders, setUserActiveTenders] = useState([]);
    const [userID, setUID] = useState(null);
    const isLoggedIn = useRef(false);
    const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
    const [loggedIn, setLoggedIn] = useState(false);
    const [userRFIlist, setUserRFIlist] = useState([]);
    const [allRFIs, setAllRFIs] = useState([]);
    const [userRFIs, setRFIs] = useState([]);
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
    const [loadingTenders, setLoadingTenders] = useState(true); 
    const [loadingRFIs, setLoadingRFIs] = useState(true);
    const [loadingUserData, setLoadingUserData] = useState(true);

    const fetchAllTenders = async () => {
        try {
          setLoadingTenders(true);
          const querySnapshot = await getDocs(collection(db, "tenders"));
          const tenders = querySnapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({
            id: doc.id,
            ...doc.data(),
          }));
          setAllTenders(tenders);
          console.log("All Tenders fetched successfully");
          console.log("Updated All Tenders state:", allTenders);
          setLoadingTenders(false);
          return true;
        } catch (error) {
          console.error("Error fetching All Tenders:", error);
          setLoadingTenders(false);
          return false;
        }
      };
      
      // ...
      
      const fetchAllRFIs = async () => {
        try {
          setLoadingRFIs(true);
          const querySnapshot = await getDocs(collection(db, "RFIs"));
          const rfis = querySnapshot.docs.map((doc) => {
            const tenderId = doc.data().tender;
            const tender = allTenders.find((tender) => tender.id === tenderId);
      
            return {
              id: doc.data().id,
              progress: doc.data().progress,
              query: doc.data().query,
              resolved: doc.data().resolved,
              responses: doc.data().responses,
              status: doc.data().status,
              tender: tender,
            };
          });
          setAllRFIs(rfis);
          console.log("All RFIs fetched successfully");
          console.log("Updated All RFIs state:", allRFIs);
          setLoadingRFIs(false);
          return true;
        } catch (error) {
          console.error("Error fetching All RFIs:", error);
          setLoadingRFIs(false);
          return false;
        }
      };
      
      // ...
      
      const fetchUserData = async () => {
        try {
          setLoadingUserData(true);
          const userDocRef = doc(db, 'users', userID);
          const docSnapshot = await getDoc(userDocRef);
      
          if (docSnapshot.exists()) {
            const userData = docSnapshot.data();
            const t = {
              tenders: userData.tenders || [],
            };
            const items = allTenders.filter((tender) =>
              t.tenders.includes(tender.id)
            );
      
            const r = {
              RFIs: userData.rfis || [],
            };
      
            const rs = allRFIs.filter((rfi) => r.RFIs.includes(rfi.id));
      
            setUserRFIlist(rs);
            setUserActiveTenders(items);
            console.log("User data fetched successfully");
            console.log("Updated User Active Tenders state:", userActiveTenders);
            console.log("Updated user RFIs: ", userRFIlist);
          } else {
            console.log('User not found');
          }
          setLoadingUserData(false);
        } catch (error) {
          console.error('Error getting user document:', error);
          setLoadingUserData(false);
        }
      };

    useEffect(() => {

        const fetchData = async () => {
            try {
                setLoading(true);
                // Check if userID is available
                if (userID) {
                    await fetchAllRFIs();
                    await fetchAllTenders();
                    await fetchUserData();
                }
            } catch (error) {
                console.error('Error fetching data:', error);
            } finally {
                setLoading(false);
            }
        };

        const user = auth.currentUser;

        if (user) { 
            setLoggedIn(true);
            const uid = user.uid;
            console.log('A USER IS LOGGED IN')
            setUID(uid)
            fetchData();
        } else {
            setLoggedIn(false);
        }
        
    }, [userID]);

    if (loadingTenders || loadingRFIs || loadingUserData) {
        return <div>Loading...</div>;
      }
    return(
        //rest of the content here
)}
```

I think the issue may be to do with the userID being loaded as null initially, so no data can be loaded. However I am not certain and am stumped.

Answer (score 1):

- **Use Effect Callback**: Consider using a separate `useEffect` for fetching user data that triggers only when `userID` changes. This
  ensures that user data is fetched as soon as `userID` is available.
- **Concurrent Fetching**: Fetch `tenders` and `RFIs` concurrently using
  `Promise.all` to optimize loading time.
- **State Dependency in `fetchUserData`**: Be cautious about using the state
  immediately after setting it. Since `fetchUserData` depends on the data
  from `fetchAllTenders` and `fetchAllRFIs`, consider passing this data
  directly to `fetchUserData` as arguments instead of relying on state.
- Debugging: Use `console.log` strategically to check the values of
  important variables at each stage of your data fetching and rendering
  process. This can help you identify exactly where the delay or issue
  is occurring.

Here's a revised approach for your useEffect and data fetching functions:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
        try {
            setLoading(true);
            const [tenders, rfis] = await Promise.all([
                fetchAllTenders(),
                fetchAllRFIs(),
            ]);

            if (userID) {
                await fetchUserData(userID, tenders, rfis);
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error fetching data:', error);
        } finally {
            setLoading(false);
        }
    };

    const user = auth.currentUser;
    if (user) { 
        setLoggedIn(true);
        setUID(user.uid);
        console.log('A USER IS LOGGED IN');
    } else {
        setLoggedIn(false);
    }

}, [userID]);

// Adjust fetchUserData to accept tenders and rfis as parameters
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, there's still the issue of having to hot reload by changing the file slightly to actually get the data to load